# Can one have a vector containing class templates in c++?

Tags: c++, list, class, templates, vector

I would like to create a structure/class that has at least one member variable that has generic type. T can be anything from a bitset to a char array. Lets call it "Field".

Then, I would like to have a list/vector/array containing multiple instances of Field objects.

Would such a data structure be possible in C++?

This is how my solutions looks like right now and it isn't compiling because of

> error C3203: 'Field' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a
>   template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type
>   error C2955: 'Field' : use of class template requires template
>   argument list

```
class Main
{
public:

    template<typename T> class Field {
        public:
            CString name;
            bool state;
            T actualValue;
    };

    vector<Field> m_Message;
};
```

...

```
Field field1 = new Field();
field1.actualValue = 1;

Field field2 = new Field();
field2.actualValue = 1.1;

vector<Field> message;

message.push_back(field1);
message.push_back(field2);
```

It's my first time posting on stack overflow, so I apologize for any bad formating or question ambiguity.

Comment: It's not a template class, it's a class template, aka a recipe for building classes. But `vector` expects a complete type, not a recipe. Still, you might want to take a look at `boost::any`.

Comment: `vector<Field<???>> m_Message;` `Main::Field<???> *field1 = new Main::Field<???>();`

Comment: Aside from the problems mentioned above, you may want to make the `Main` class a template, then use a `vector<T>` inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly. Here's the problem, as we iterate over the vector

```
for (...:iteraor e....) {
   e->m_Message.actualValue;
}
```

what is the type of *actualValue*? You might say that it's different each time, but C++ dosn't work that way, each expression in your code has 1 type. (Besides the template thing, but that basically just gives you a new copy of your code for each type you put in)

You could create a base class for all of your Field's and then but references (but not copies into a vector).

```
class FieldBase {
    public:
        CString name;
        bool state;
};
template<typename T>
class Field public: FieldBase
{
 public:
   T actualValue;
};
vector<FieldBase*> m_Message;
```

Then you'll need some to dispatch on what kind of message you are dealing with. Overloaded method maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Each instantiated template class has different data type. At the time you declare vector the Field should have defined data type, but here it is not.

I guess, what you are looking for is a variant class. Some libraries like Qt offer variants e.g. QVariant.

However a variant itself is not a template class, and can't be. The variant classes are often  implemented using unions and void pointers. It is the implementation of dynamic-type behaviour. The type is dynamic at run time. In contrast, templates are not dynamic at run time. The type is determined at compile time, otherwise compiler either brakes, or there is no code generated.

Answer (score 0):

Above all, your example code is wrong. The correct version will be

```
Field<int> field1 = Field<int>();
field1.actualValue = 1;

Field<double> field2 = Field<double>();
field2.actualValue = 1.1;
```

Here's *not* Java, isn't it?

---

First, you should know `Field<int>` and `Field<double>` are **different types**. Look at your example.

```
template <typename T> class Field { ... };

Field<int> field1 = Field<int>();
field1.actualValue = 1;

Field<double> field2 = Field<double>();
field2.actualValue = 1.1;
```

Compiler may think like this:

```
class Field_int { /* int version of Field */ };
Field_int field1 = Field_int();
field1.actualValue = 1;

class Field_double { /* double version of Field */ };
Field_double field1 = Field_double();
field1.actualValue = 1;
```

That's how *template instantiation* works - **in compile time**. When compiler meet `Field<int>`, it *create* a new class from your template code.

Now you're trying to push different versions of `Field` into `vector`.

```
vector<???> message;
message.push_back(field1);
message.push_back(field2);
```

As you know, `vector` can hold array of same type. `Field<int>` and `Field<double>` are *not* the same type.

---

So, how to do it? Since C++'s templates is run during compile time, we had this problem. Then, how about doing it during *runtime*?

I suggest you to use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html). It can change its type during runtime, so we can use that instead of template.

(If you don't know about [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), take a look - you'll love it.)

You can make `Field::actualValue` `boost::any`.

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class Field
{
    CString name;
    bool state;
    boost::any actualValue;
};

vector<Field> messages;

Field field1;
field1.actualValue = 1;
messages.push_back(field1);

Field field2;
field1.actualValue = 1.1;
messages.push_back(field2);
```

Answer (score 0):

With enough metaprogramming, you can do almost anything.

In this case, you might want to look at `boost::variant`, which stores one of any of a fixed set of types, and gives you type-safe access to it.  Failing that, `boost::any` can hold one of anything, **but** you can only get types out if you know the exact type you stored in it.

Next, the technique of type erasure/run time concepts lets you abstract a finite set of operations on your type, and store it in an any-equivalent, yet allow you to do that finite set of operations on the data.

Possibly easier would be to invent a base class, store `std::unique_ptr`s to it, and store derived instances.  Use dynamic cast to get at the particular subtype if needed.

If none of these work, you could always run a scripting language, and write your code in that language instead of C++.  Many scripting languages can be embedded into C++, and serious applications often use such embedded scripting languages.